# When does the process.nextTick() run in node?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

```
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const start = Date.now();
const OS = require("os");

fs.readFile("test-file", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Timer");
  }, 1500);
  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log("next tick");
  });
  crypto.pbkdf2Sync("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512");
  console.log(Date.now() - start);
  crypto.pbkdf2Sync("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512");
  console.log(Date.now() - start);
  crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512", () => {
    console.log(Date.now() - start, "ASYNC");
  });
});

fs.readFile("test-file", () => {
  console.log("in here");
});
```

output:

```
1028
2051
next tick
in here
Timer
3074 ASYNC
```

From my prior knowledge, i thought that process.nextTick is run after each phase before moving to the next phase.

However since the "In here" is coming from the I/O polling and also since the setTimout (which was already timed out as 1500 ms have already passed as in the output) is logged after "In here", it is clear that the nextTick is executed before event loop shifts from i/o polling.

What i now understand is that process.nexttick is executed in the current phase before a new function is passed to the thread. A description is given here: https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll but i am not able to understand what exactly does "Here, an operation is defined as a transition from the underlying C/C++ handler, and handling the JavaScript that needs to be executed." mean.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-process-nexttick

there are two functions you have given which executes asap that executes in a event loop
but in first fs.readFile() function process.nextTick() gets executed after going through the first fs function, setTimeout executes at end of the process.nextTick()

so basically process.nextTick() gets executed at the end of the current operation in a function
but async function will return when it completes its operation and returns into the message que then it returns its output.